# Getting all suggestions from the SuggestBox in GWT

Tags: gwt

How to create a filter tree in GWT using CellTree, a filter tree is some Tree which has an filter(TextBox) where we can enter values for the leaf node. Once we start entering values we get the tree branches along with leaf nodes reflected on the Tree panel(we have our tree inside a panel). For reference : http://www.sencha.com/examples/explorer.html#filtertree

We can develop such FilterTree easily in GXT, but we have an requirement to develop it in GWT, not in GXT. Can I have some replies with a short and simple sample code on FilterTree in GWT, or at least any links to refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't exist natively in GWT.

You'll have to write some code! You can achieve this with a [TextBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextBox.html) with a [KeyUpHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyUpHandler.html).

I would suggest implementing your own Tree, because the Tree that comes with GWT isn't good for your use case. It's API won't allow you to hide and show leaves easily.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have already started working on it, I'm using Cell Tree of GWT and yes you are correct, its too difficult to show and hide the nodes in case of GWT. I have almost given all my hopes, as I'm stuck now. Can you help in getting some idea as to how to proceed with skeleton code to start a fresh FilterTree again. I'm stuck right at how can I show and hide the nodes ?? More over I went through GXT code, its too complicated and makes thorough use of TreeStore. What should I do to get this FilterTree any help would be appreciated.